# Como alterar local de campos no Django?

Tags: django, django-admin

Quando cadastramos nossas models no `admin.py` do django elas são mostradas como segue abaixo:

```py
@admin.register(Beneficio)
class BeneficioAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('nome', 'situacao')
```

Elas serão mostradas dessa maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na imagem em questão, tenho todos apps cadastrados, `Pessoa` e `Vaga`, e eles tem alguns campos que eu gostaria que ficassem em uma sessão separada, em vez de serem mostrados onde estão. Ex: Uma seção chamada `configuração` onde eu possa colocar `Beneficios` e `Setors`. Eu tentei criar um App chamado configuração apenas para efeitos de teste e adicionei esse seguinte trecho de código no `admin.py` dele:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from vaga.models import Beneficio


@admin.register(Beneficio)
class BeneficioAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('nome', 'situacao')
```

Porém, o beneficio ainda é mostrado junto de Vaga, Então isso não resolveu meu problema.

Repare que  `Beneficios` e `Setor` são de apps diferentes, mas por questão de organização eu gostaria que eles ficassem próximos um do outro, pois haverá um usuário que irá alteralos com frequência.

como isso pode ser feito no django?